# How to convert the list into a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I have a list like this.

```
ls = ['Size:10,color:red,', 'Size:10,color: blue,']
```

I want to convert the list into this format.

```
[{'Size':'10','color':'red'}, {'Size':'10','color': 'blue'}]
```

What I have tried is:

```
[dict([pair.split(":", 1)]) for pair in ls]

  # It gave me output like this.

[{'Size': '10,color:red,'}, {'Size': '10,color: blue,'}]
```

But this method works if the list is like this `['color:blue,']` but didn't worked properly with the above list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see that `for pair in ls` in your list comprehension is already doubtful, because elements of `ls` are not pairs. Each element actually contains a sequence of pairs.

There will be two loops needed here, one to iterate the outer list, and then another one to iterate within each value, since those values are actually strings consisting of multiple fields.

While this is possible with a nested list comprehension, it will be easier (and more readable) if you break the problem down into simpler parts rather than trying to fit it all into one-line.

```
result = []
for text in ls:
    d = {}
    pairs = text.strip(",").split(",")
    for pair in pairs:
        key, val = pair.split(":")
        d[key] = val.strip()
    result.append(d)
```